# Java - What is the order of operations in this recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, factorial

I seem to be a little stuck on really grasping recursions so I can use them.

This is the example I found on a tutorial.

I want to verify to see if I am understanding this correctly.

```
public class SolveRecursion {



public void recursionPerform(){

System.out.println(fact(4));


}
public static long fact(long n){

    if (n <= 1){
        return n;
    }
    else{
        return n * fact(n-1);
    }

}
}
```

Let us set n to 4.

In that case, is this what happens?
(Sorry for the confusing format, I did my best)

**(Is n(4) <=1, No), Else, n(4) * (Is (n-1=3) <=1, No), Else, n(3) * (Is (n-1=2) <= 1, No), Else * (Is (n-1<=1), Yes) * n(1)**

Comment: You could run this in the debugger, or add print statements, and then you'd be able to see the order of operations for yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the print statements, made things a little easier to see.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's the order of operations:

```
n = 4
Is 4 <= 1? No
4 * fact(3)
    n = 3
    Is 3 <= 1? No
4 * 3 * fact(2)
        n = 2
        Is 2 <= 1? No
4 * 3 * 2 * fact(1)
            n = 1
            Is 1 <= 1? Yes, return 1.  // Base Case
4 * 3 * 2 * 1
24
```

Comment: Makes a lot of sense now, I think I overcomplicated it in my head. It is way more linear than I had originally thought it to be.

Thank you.